# How to satisfy Comparable.S with my type

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to make a set (using `Core.Std.Set`) of my datatype for a literal, so that I can have the performance benefits of using sets for my clause type (rather than defining `type clause = literal list`).

```
type atom = string

type sign = Pos | Neg

type literal = sign * atom

module Literal : sig
  type t = literal
  include Comparable.S with type t := t  
end = struct
  module T = struct
    type t = literal
    let compare t1 t2 =
      match (t1,t2) with
      | ((Pos,_), (Neg,_)) -> 1
      | ((Neg,_), (Pos,_)) -> -1
      | ((_,x), (_,y)) -> String.compare x y
  end
  include T
  include Comparable.Make(T)
end

module Clause = Set.Make(Literal)
```

I was following Real World OCaml, [Chapter 13. Maps and Hash Tables](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/maps-and-hash-tables.html) at the *Satisfying the Comparable.S Interface* section. The problem is that we don't have the `sexp_of_t` and `t_of_sexp` functions. But when I change the `type t = literal` line to `type t = literal with sexp` the compiler says `Error: Unbound value literal_of_sexp`.

This leads me to believe either (a) I have to implement the sexp functions myself (I'm not sure how I'd approach this), or (b) I shouldn't be trying to satisfy `Comparable.S` anyway (for some reason like it would only work for primitive types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can still use plain old `camlp4`. It is not deprecated, and most of core versions on most of compiler versions still require it. And don't be afraid, that your code will depend on it, when needed you can automatically translate you `camlp4` code to a `ppx` code. So far, I would recommend you to stick with `camlp4`.

Using `with` notation, your code can be rewritten as:

```
type atom = string with sexp,compare
type sign = Pos | Neg with sexp,compare
type literal = sign * atom with sexp,compare 

module Literal = struct
  type t = literal with sexp,compare
  include Comparable.Make(struct
      type nonrec t = t with sexp,compare
    end)
end

module Clause = Set.Make(Literal)
```

But there is one thing, that you should know. There is no need to use `Set.Make`. `Comparable` interface provides sets and maps inside, so, you should write:

```
module Clause = Literal.Set
```

there is also `Literal.Map`. If you're looking for hash tables and hash sets, then you `Hashable` interface, that will give you `Literal.Table` and `Literal.Hash_set`. You can implement using `Hashable.Make` functor, and adding its result to the `Literal` module:

```
  include Hashable.Make(struct
      type nonrec t = t with sexp,compare
      let hash = Hashtbl.hash
    end)
```

Also you can use `Identifiable` interface that is a sum of `Comparable` and `Hashable`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing `type t = literal with sexp` requests to generate functions for `t`, which will be `t_of_sexp` and `sexp_of_t`. However, the implementations of these functions assume that corresponding functions are available for `literal` because `t` is defined in terms of `literal`. In other words you also need to add `with sexp` onto `type literal = ...`, which will in turn require you to do so for `sign` and `atom`.

Also note that you're using camlp4, but many tools such as the syntax extensions you're using are migrating to ppx (the RWO book is out of date on this point). Instead of `with sexp` as supported by `sexplib.syntax`, you are encouraged to now do `[@@deriving sexp]` as supported by `ppx_sexp_conv`.

Here's a complete working example:

```
$ cat foo.ml
open Core.Std

type atom = string [@@deriving sexp,compare]
type sign = Pos | Neg [@@deriving sexp,compare]
type literal = sign * atom [@@deriving sexp,compare]

module Literal : sig
  type t = literal [@@deriving sexp,compare]
  include Comparable.S with type t := t
end = struct
  module T = struct
    type t = literal [@@deriving sexp,compare]
  end
  include T
  include Comparable.Make(T)
end

module Clause = Set.Make(Literal)
```

Your `compare` function is perfectly fine, but I'm also showing you how to use ppx_compare, which generates `compare` functions. Compile like this:

```
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -package core,ppx_sexp_conv,ppx_compare -thread -c foo.ml
```

You can add `-dsource` to view the generated code. You can't use `corebuild` as RWO recommends because it assumes camlp4 is being used, but that is incompatible with ppx, so you'll get an error.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is deprecated. It is a new feature of the infrastructure, that has an intersecting functionality with `camlp4`. The latter is still a worthwhile tool, that so far has a better support in current infrastructure and works for all version of the compiler and core (unlike the `ppx`)

Comment: I've edited to avoid suggesting that camlp4 is deprecated.